# VMWare: Virtual Disk performance exceptionally bad

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

My virtual machine has problems with disk performance.

On the Host machine, i get a disk-score of for example:

> Disk Sequential Read:  **3538 Mbytes/sec**
> Disk Sequential Write: **2858 Mbytes/sec**
> IOPS **107 Mbytes/sec**

While running a disk test, the drive goes up to 100% load, in idle mode (no VM starte, no test running) the disk load is 1-2%. When starting the VM and running the VM idle, it goes to 3-5% load

When i run the test on the VM again, the disk load never goes over ~30% and i'm getting the following results

> Disk Sequential Read:  **1935 Mbytes/sec**
> Disk Sequential Write: **1546 Mbytes/sec**
> IOPS **35 Mbytes/sec**

The OS is Windows Server 2019, the disk is configured as single disk and as "NVME" in VmWare configuration, since the physical disk is an nvme

How can i increase the virtual disk performance, and why is it so slow at the momement?

Comment: I think you are hitting max out of NVMe controller. Check the following article:
https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/VMware_Performance_Comparison_SCSI_Controller_and_NVMe_Controller
In case you need max out of NVMe, install ESXi and do a PCI Passthrough. TO share NVMe over network you can use Starwinds NVMf target. 
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-nvme-of-initiator

Comment: I switched now to hyper-V, there performance is almost identical to true disk